# how do u replace part of a each "elements" of a dataframe column with something else

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to change a columns of dates that have a defaulted value that is invalid in pandas date-time conversion. Say I have:

```
index Date_posted Voted_on id .... 

0     2002-10-00   ...     ...

1     2002-10-20   ...     ...

2     2002-09-00   ...     ...
```

There is 140,000 entries so there is many variations to this.

Is there a way to change like : 2002-10-00 to 2002-10-01 without changing the '00' in 2002? The format is always in : Years-Months-Dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use str.replace

```
df['Date_posted'] = df['Date_posted'].str.replace('-00', '-01')
pd.to_datetime(df['Date_posted'])

0   2002-10-01
1   2002-10-20
2   2002-09-01
```

Comment: awesome i tried using dataframe.replace and pandas infer_objects but those didnt work